# confidence ellipse came out as y shape

Tags: r

I drew the confidence ellipse for mu1 and mu 2 i used following code based on means and variance inverse I got but the ellipse came out as Y shape:

[image]

```
library(car)
library(SIBER)
ellipse<-function(mu1,mu2)
{
  30*1.155461e-05*(1860.500-mu1)^2+ 30*4.11493e-07*(8354.133-mu2)^2
  - 60*1.98504e-06*(1860.500-mu1)*(8354.133-mu2)
}
mu1<-seq(1650,2100,50)
mu2<-seq(7000,9500,50)
z <- t(sapply(mu1,ellipse,mu2))
contour(mu1,mu2,z, 
        levels=6.91, 
        drawlabels=T, 
        axes=T,
        frame.plot=T, 
        xlab="mu1 (stf)",
        ylab="mu2 (ben strnegth)",
        main = "A 95% confidence ellipse for mu = (mu1,mu2)")
points(1860.5,8354.133)
segments(0,8354.133,1860.500,8354.133)
segments(1860.500,0,1860.500,8354.133)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you want to show results on your screen it's usually easier and more efficient to take a screenshot or partial screenshot (do a web search to see how to do this on your operating system) rather than taking a photo with your phone/camera ...

Answer (score 2):

A surprisingly subtle typo.  In your function definition,

```r
ellipse<-function(mu1,mu2) {
  30*1.155461e-05*(1860.500-mu1)^2+ 30*4.11493e-07*(8354.133-mu2)^2
  - 60*1.98504e-06*(1860.500-mu1)*(8354.133-mu2)
}
```

you broke the line *before the minus sign*; the first line is a complete R expression, so R computes it (and discards the result since you didn't assign it to a value), and then computes the second line **as a second expression** and returns it. In other words, your function is only returning the cross-term (`60*1.98504e-06 ...`).

Possible solutions:

- put parentheses around the whole expression
- move the minus sign to the end of the first line, so that R recognizes that the expression isn't finished yet

You may find the `ellipse` package or the `ellipse` function in the `car` package useful ...